# Reference code files from external folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, project

I try to reference a collection of c# code to a console project in visual studio.

1. I want to keep the referenced code **outside** the console project folder.
2. I want the code to **automatically** update when it gets changed in the external position.
3. The referenced codes folder structure should stay intact. (~100 files)

Is there a way of referencing/linking the code without updating everytime? "Include in Project" only works if the code is inside a solution folder.

Comment: The external code is inside a project or it's just a set of .cs files?

Comment: It is just a set of .cs file

Comment: If no one builds the external code, I suppose your solution should. In this case, the answer given by canton7 is the best choice.

Comment: You could consider building a Nuget package for the referenced code and setting up a local feed of Nuget packages.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add a "link" to code files outside of your project. This doesn't make a copy of the files.

Right-click your project -> Add -> Existing Item..., and browse to the file(s). Then click the down-arrow on the "Add" button and select "Add As Link":

[image: Add As Link]

Linked files appear with a blue arrow in the Solution Explorer:

[image: Linked file in Solution Explorer]

---

If you want to reference an entire folder structure of code, you'll need to edit your `.csproj`. Something like:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="..\SomeDir\**\*.cs" Link="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Adjust `..\SomeDir` to be the path to your code. The `**\*.cs` is of course a pattern to recursively include all `.cs` files. `%(RecursiveDir)`, `%(Filename)`, and `%(Extension)` are MSBuild placeholders.

Comment: When you look at my "simlink" solution, is this equal, or if not, what is the better solution? May it be, that your solution does not respect folder structure? My simlink solution allows to keep the subfolders in place

Comment: @Mechandrius They're just different. This solution only uses VS. If you share your project with others, this will look for the files in the same relative location, whereas yours will require setting up the symlink again. Which is best depends on your circumstances

Comment: Can you elaborate the reference for the entire folder? What does RecursiveDir stand for? For example my code lies in "C:\Folder\Code" and my c# project lies in "C:\Projects\ConsoleApp". How would my include-line look like and where exaclty would I put it in the .csproj?

Comment: And it needs to be put into the <project> tags or into <propertygroup>?

Comment: @Mechandrius In an `<ItemGroup>`, along with all of your other `<Content>` tags

Comment: @Mechandrius Are they `.cs` files?

Comment: @Mechandrius From your description I've no idea I'm afraid. If `Utility.cs` is shown in your project in the Solution Explorer, the types inside it should be available to other files in your project

Comment: @Mechandrius D'oh sorry! That's my bad. I'll fix the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I organise my git repos in a flat structure:

- core
- shared1
- website1
- website2

Where websites 1 and 2 both reference core and shared1.

When I add project references to core and shared1 from websites 1 and 2, they remain intact because they are both in the same relative location from the point of view of the websites.

Additionally, I organise my solution to mirror the external repo configuration, e.g.

- core (solution folder)

  - corelibrary.csproj
- shared1 (solution folder)

  - sharedlibrary.csproj
- website1services.csproj
- website1.csproj

Comment: In my case, the referenced code must be able to be stored in a parent folder of the project. So your solution will not really work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution, but I am curious if there is a better one. I am on Windows and using a simbolic link

```
cmd /c mklink /d /j _LinkedCode ..\..\..\_Code
```

then I can use "Include in Project" in visual studio

Comment: This somehow throws up the problem, that the code is treated as duplicate.